# Testing Numpy array to see if it is in column form

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In my function, sometimes I get a result that is a 1 dimensional numpy array in 2D form, so that it's shape is nx1 (n,1).  Other times, I might get it in the form 1xn array.shape = (1,n)

Other times, I get just a numpy array whose shape is (n,).

when I run the following tests, I get an error on the one hand, and a false positive on the other (since the length of a shape attribute is always greater than 1, apparently):

```
    y_predicted = forest.predict(testX)
    if y_predicted.shape[1] != None:
        y_predicted = y_predicted.T[0]
```

and

```
    y_predicted = forest.predict(testX)
    if len(y_predicted.shape) > 1:
        y_predicted = y_predicted.T[0]
```

I just need to make sure the final shape of y is always in the form (n,) rather than (n,1) or (1,n)...

Comment: `squeeze`, `ravel` and `flatten` will all do this job; but read their docs so you understand their differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`numpy.squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

> `numpy.squeeze(a)` removes single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array.

Example:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3]])
>>> x.shape
(1, 3)
>>> np.squeeze(x)
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.squeeze(x).shape
(3,)
```

Comment: Good answer. Was unaware of this method.